# Recursive type for nested record in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, nested, record

Since version 3.7, TypeScript has support for recursive types, which I thought would help me create a proper type for a nested record structure, but so far I haven't managed to make the compiler happy with my attempts.

Let's forget about generics and say as a minimal example, that I have an object, which has numeric values at arbitrary depths behind string keys.

```
type NestedRecord = Record<string, number | NestedRecord>

const test: NestedRecord = {
  a: 10,
  b: {
    c: 20,
    d: 30,
  }
}
```

This typing would make sense to me, but the compiler gives me the following error:
`Type alias 'NestedRecord' circularly references itself.`

Is there some limitation of the support for recursive types that I am not aware of? If so, how could a type for this structure be achieved?

---

*Edit: Based on the [answer of @jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76583105/1831096) I ended up using the following generic definition:*

```
type NestedRecord<T> = { [key: string]: NestedRecordField<T> }
type NestedRecordField<T> = T | NestedRecord<T>
```

In my case separating these made sense, as a recursive function operating on such records needed the `NestedRecordField` type anyway, but the following one line solution is also valid:

```
type NestedRecord<T> = { [key: string]: T | NestedRecord<T> }
```

Comment: What should be the limit?

Comment: Don't use `Record<string, number | NestedRecord>`, use the equivalent `{[k: string]: number | NestedRecord}` instead.  The compiler can't "see" into the utility type `Record` to know that the recursion is safe.  Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAchDOwIBMBKEDGB7ATsgPAFBRQAyAlgLbnBQQAeSAdsvFEwK6UBGEOUAXigBWADTEoAYQ44cEJrQbNWUDkwDWTLAHcmAbQC6gqIfEA+Y+mx4iJRDnJMA5uJIAfdl144JHgBTSsvLAegDkADbyTsAAFqFGSvIqFNTAEiQkAPzsEABufOkZAFywCEhomLgEKTSiJgB0jYFyCnVqmjpMBmYAlIRmANyEhNhMiFBIiCVwiChWVcYA3hIAhiUAjAAMrlDcJcsZUBglAEzbhcglAMznJAC+4ndDQA) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions! @jcalz, I like your suggestion the most, and I would be happy to learn more about what happens under the hood / behind the scenes, so if you have the time to write up a more detailed answer, I will make sure to read through it and accept it! :) [I have assumed, that the definition of `Record` would have been treated pretty transparently and essentially unfolded, but it turns out not to be the case.]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [microsoft/TypeScript#41164](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41164) for a canonical answer to this question.

TypeScript allows *some* circular definitions, but some are prohibited.  You can't have `type Oops = Oops`, for example.  If you have a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type like `type Foo<T> = ...`, then it's not clear whether `type Bar = Foo<Bar>` will be allowed or prohibited unless the compiler is willing to eagerly substitute `Foo` with its definition. And the compiler doesn't do this; it *defers* such evaluation (lest compiler performance suffer dramatically).  So the compiler will reject `type Bar = Foo<Bar>` even if it turns out that the definition of `Foo` is harmless.  It's a design limitation of TypeScript.

So even though [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) is harmless for recursive types in its `V` parameter, the compiler fails to notice that, and you get an error.

---

The recommend approach here is to replace `Record<K, V>` with its definition `{[P in K]: V}`.  For `Record<string, V>` that would look like `{[P in string]: V}`, which evaluates to a type with the string [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) `{[k: string]: V}`.  So you can use that directly:

```
type NestedRecord =
    { [k: string]: number | NestedRecord }; // okay
```

And then your assignment works as expected:

```
const test: NestedRecord = {
    a: 10,
    b: {
        c: 20,
        d: 30,
    }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAchDOwIBMBKEDGB7ATsqAvALABQU5UA3lANoDWAXFIjgJYB2A5gLpPsCuAWwBGEHFAA+sBEjSZc+AL4BuKAHo1ULHQCGIUqWztEUJIiZxEKdNjyEqpClB1MAjAAYANI4rCmlHydyDCYAJi9AoOQmAGYIsgpFUkUgA)